# Problem with Splitting Up a String and Putting it Into an Array in BASH on a Mac

Tags: arrays, string, bash, macos

I have been trying to split up a string and putting it into an Array in Bash on my Mac without success.

Here is my sample code:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a allDisks
allDisksString="`ls /dev/disk* | grep -e 'disk[0-9]s.*' | awk '{ print $NF }'`"
#allDisksString="/dev/disk0s1 /dev/disk1s1"
echo allDisksString is $allDisksString
IFS=' ' read -ra allDisks <<< "$allDisksString"
echo allDIsks is "$allDisks"
echo The second item in allDisks is "${allDisks[1]}"
for disk in "${allDisks[@]}"
do
    printf "Loop $disk\n"
done
```

And below is the output:

```
allDisksString is /dev/disk0s1 /dev/disk0s2 /dev/disk0s3 /dev/disk0s4 /dev/disk1s1
allDIsks is /dev/disk0s1
The second item in allDisks is 
Loop /dev/disk0s1
```

Interesting if I execute the following in the Mac Terminal:

```
ls /dev/disk* | grep -e 'disk[0-9]s.*' | awk '{ print $NF }'
```

I get the following output

```
/dev/disk0s1
/dev/disk0s2
/dev/disk0s3
/dev/disk0s4
/dev/disk1s1
```

So I have also tried setting IFS to IFS=$'\n' without any success.

So no luck in getting a list of my drives into an array.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` only reads one line.

Use an assignment instead. When assigning to an array, you need to use parentheses after the = sign:

```
#!/bin/bash
disks=( $(ls /dev/disk* | grep -e 'disk[0-9]s.*' | awk '{ print $NF }') )
echo ${disks[1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're making this much more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need to use `ls`, you can just use a wildcard to match the device names you want, and put that in an array assignment.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a allDisks
allDisks=(/dev/disk[0-9]s*)
echo allDIsks is "$allDisks"
echo The second item in allDisks is "${allDisks[1]}"
for disk in "${allDisks[@]}"
do
    printf "Loop $disk\n"
done
```

Comment: P.S.  There is an small error in your code that was carried over from my code.  The third line in your code above really should be:  echo allDIsks is "${allDisks[*]}"

Comment: It's only an error if you really intended to print the whole array.